# Catch when php file written to

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to know if its possible to force PHP to execute as a file rather than being overwritten?

I have set the sendmail -X option for logging which will happily log to a file. When I set it to point to a PHP file it appended to the actual file. Is there anyway (I'm using Ubuntu) to effectively run the file rather than it being written to?

The file currently reads (which I would like to execute):

```
<?php
$pointer = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');

file_put_contents('/home/www/dev1/log.log',$pointer);
?>
```

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying. What file are you writing to?

Comment: I want to replace this script in time which logs to a MySQL database but effectively I want sendmail to execute this script. I was trying the route of -X.

Comment: Oh, so you want the `sendmail` command to write to the STDIN of this PHP file?

Comment: Please note that `$pointer` is a resource and is not directly applicable with `file_put_contents`. Maybe you want to use `stream_copy_to_stream` instead.

Comment: But the file itself would still have the log contents written to it rather than executing. Not sure why the -1 as well.

Comment: But yes I want sendmail to write to STDIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bash, you can try [process substituion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
sendmail other-args -X >(php your-php-file.php)
```

This will pass the contents to your PHP file's stdin directly.

However, use [`stream_copy_to_stream`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php), because if you use `stream_get_contents` or other one-time functions like that, nothing will be written until the process closes.

Comment: I don't believe I am using bash. I'm using the default ubuntu.

Comment: @AntonyHatton what is default ubuntu? The normal login shell of most Linux machines is bash.

Comment: How do you launch the `sendmail` process? Try `echo $0` to see what shell you are using. You can also try `echo 'sendmail other-args -X >(php your-php-file.php)' | bash`.

Comment: So I tried `sendmail_path = "sendmail -t -i -r me@me.com -X > (php /home/www/maillog.php) | bash"` and other variants and unfortunately no success

Comment: It is `>(php file.php)` not `> (php file.php)`. Don't add that space.

Comment: Wait, why do you need to put that into php.ini?

Comment: because thats where I'm setting the sendmail config.

Comment: sorry had to delete that comment as it had my personal details in!